# Counterexample to Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem in $\ell_{\infty}$ space

Tags: banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Brouwer fixed point theorem states that if $f: B^n \rightarrow B^n$ is continuous map from unit ball $B^n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into itself, then there is some $x \in B^n$ such that $f(x) = x$.
This result fails in infinite dimensional spaces and im trying to find continuous (or even lipschitz) map $f: B_{\ell_{\infty}} \rightarrow B_{\ell_{\infty}}$, where $B_{\ell_{\infty}}$ is unit ball in real Banach space $\ell_{\infty}$, without fixed points. I had troubles in finding such example so I started from smaller space $c_0$ (of all real sequences $(x_n)$ such that $\lim x_n = 0$). There is simple isometry $f: B_{c_0} \rightarrow B_{c_0}$ without fixed point given by $f(x) = (1,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$. We can pass to bigger space $c$ of all convergent sequences and consider $f: B_c \rightarrow B_c$ but now $f$ has fixed point $(1,1,1,\ldots)$. Little modification gives $\hat{f}(x) = (1,-1,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ and we get continuous map $\hat{f}:B_{c} \rightarrow B_{c}$ without fixed point. Im trying to extend these ideas to space $\ell_{\infty}$ but im stuck. Any hints and comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "this map no longer works"? I see no reason for that, and neither do I see why the same map doesn't work in $l_\infty$.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov The sequence $(1,1,1,...)$, which (while not in $c_0$) is a point in $c$ and in the unit ball of $\mathscr{l}_\infty$, is a fixed point of that map.

Comment: You are right, for some reason I read "no longer works" as "no longer well-defined".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $f:B_{l_\infty} \to B_{l_\infty}$ defined as
$$
f(x)=f((x_k))=(1-\|x\|,\sqrt{|x_1|}, \sqrt{|x_2|},\sqrt{|x_3|}, \dots).
$$
Assume $y=f(y)$ for some $y=(y_k) \in B_{l_\infty}$. Then
$$
y_1=1-\|y\|, ~ y_2=\sqrt{|y_1|}, ~ y_3=\sqrt{|y_2|}=|y_1|^{1/4}, ~ y_4=\sqrt{|y_3|}=|y_1|^{1/8}, \dots
$$
hence $y_k=|y_1|^{1/2^{k-1}}$ $(k \ge 2)$.

1. case $\|y\|=1$: Then $(y_k)=(0)$, so $\|y\|=0$, a contradiction.
2. case $\|y\|<1$: Then $y_1 > 0$ and $y_k \to 1$ as $(k \to \infty)$. Hence $\|y\|=1$, a contradiction.

Clearly $f$ is continous, but not Lipschitz-continous.

Comment: great stuff! thank you

Comment: Great stuff, really.

Comment: Very nice construction. I hope OP approves this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your attention and answers. I tried to modify Gerd's example by replacing map $t \mapsto \sqrt{|t|}$, which is acting on coordinates, with a nicer function. I think it worked very well.

Fix $k > 1$ and consider map $f: B_{\ell_{\infty}} \rightarrow B_{\ell_{\infty}}$ given by
$$ f(x) = ( 1 - \|x\|, \varphi(k x_1), \varphi(k x_2), \varphi(k x_3), \ldots),$$
where $\varphi(t) = \min\{t,1\}$. Notice that for any $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|\varphi(t) - \varphi(s)| \leq |s - t|$, which means that $\varphi$ satisfies Lipschitz condition with constant $1$. From this it easily follows that $f$ is $k$-lipschitzian.

Now I claim that $f$ has no fixed points. Suppose $x = f(x)$ for some $x \in B_{\ell_{\infty}}$. Then
\begin{equation} 
 (1) \quad x_1 = 1 - \|x\|, \quad x_2 = \varphi(kx_1), \quad x_3 = \varphi(kx_2), \quad x_4 = \varphi(kx_3), \quad \ldots
\end{equation}
Lets consider three cases.

If $\|x\| = 1$, then it follows from (1) that $x_i = 0$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, but this is impossible.

Suppose $\|x\| \leq 1 - \frac{1}{k} < 1$. It follows that $k(1-\|x\|) \geq 1$ and consequently $x_2 = \varphi(kx_1) = \varphi(k(1-\|x\|)) = 1$. Thus  $\|x\| = 1$ contrary to the assumption.

For the last case assume $1 - \frac{1}{k} \leq \|x\| < 1$. This time we have $k(1-\|x\|) \leq 1$ and consequently $x_2 = \varphi(k(1-\|x\|)) = k(1-\|x\|)$. Now $x_3 = \varphi(kx_2) = \varphi(k^2(1-\|x\|))$ and this value is either $1$ or $k^2(1-\|x\|)$. However there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k^n(1-\|x\|) > 1$ and at some point we'll reach $x_{n+1} = 1$. Again $\|x\| = 1$ contradicting our assumption.

Comment: I would point out that for any $\psi\colon [-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ such that $\psi(x) > x$ on $(0,1)$, $\psi(0) = 0$, $\psi(1) = 1$ will work to produce $f(x) = (1-\|x\|, \psi(x))$ without a fixed point. You can take for instance $\psi(x) = x + \epsilon x(1-x^2)$ for $\epsilon$ small.  The only extra thing we would like to have is $d(x, f(x)) \le \delta > 0$ which does not hold. I wonder how to produce an example with $\delta> 0$. I want to point out that is seems that the optimal $\delta$ according to Goebel is $\le 1-\frac{1}{k}$ where $k$ is the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @orangeskid do you mean that $\inf\{\|x - f(x)\|: x \in B_{\ell_{\infty}} \} = 0$ in the above example? That would mean there is sequence $(x_n)$ in $B_{\ell_{\infty}}$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|x_n - f(x_n)\| = 0$. I don't see such sequence yet.

Comment: I added some details in my answer, not hard to see that the displacement is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a Lipschitz map that invariates the unit ball and does not have a fixed point

$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = (\sup_{i\ge 1} (1-|x_i|), x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2, \ldots)$$

Assume that $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ is a fixed point. Then we have $x_{i+1} = x_i^2$ for all $i\ge 1$, and  $x_1 = \sup_{i \ge 1}(1-|x_i|)$. But if $|x_1|< 1$ then $x_n \to 0$ so $\sup_{i\ge 1} (1-|x_i|) = 1$, while if $|x_1|=1$, then all $|x_i|=1$, so $\sup(1-|x_i|) = 0$, contradiction.

Note that $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $2$. We could choose  $|x_i|^k$ instead of $x_i^2$ ($k>1$)  that is
$$f(x) = (\|\,  1- |x| \, \|, |x|^k)$$
and get a $k$-[Lipschitz map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions).

$\bf{Added:}$

This is a comment on the methods of @Gerd and @triple backflip:

Consider a map $\phi\colon [-1,1]\to [-1,1]$, continuous such that

$\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi(1) = 1$, and $\phi(x) > x$ on $(0,1)$.

Define now the map $f(x)$ on $\ell_{\infty}$,

$$f(x_0, x_1, \ldots) = (1-\|x\|, \phi(x_0), \phi_(x_1), \ldots)$$

Assume that $x$ is a fixed point of $f$. Then we have $x_n = \phi^n(x_0)$ for all $n\ge 0$, and also $x_0= 1-\|x\|$.

Now,  notice that the sequence $x_n$ is constant $0$ if $x_0=0$, and converges to $1$ if $x_0>0$. Therefore, we cannot have $x_0 = 1-\|x\|$, and so we do not have a fixed point in the unit ball.

Notice also that for $x = (\alpha, \phi(\alpha), \phi^2(\alpha), \ldots)$, where $\alpha \in (0,1]$, we have $\|x\|=1$ and so
$$x - f(x) = \alpha$$
which can be made as small as desired.

Now, we can take $\phi$ a $k$ Lipschitz function ($k>1$) of the form

$$\phi(x) = x + \epsilon \cdot x(1-x^2)$$
for $\epsilon>0$ small.

Comment: I think there's a mistake. Take $(x_1,x_2,...)=(1, 1, ...)$ constant. Then the norm of $f(x_1,x_2,...)$ is greater than one. To see it, just evaluate its 8-th term.

Comment: @Arix94: Thanks!  Wrote a new answer in the end, the other one could not be corrected.

Comment: Nice examples (+1). In particular Lipschitz-constant arbitrarily close to $1$ is possible.

Comment: @Gerd: Thank you!  Indeed your beautiful solution got me thinking.  Now I wonder if we can get it to Lipschitz $1$.  For $\ell_1$ it is possible, not so for $\ell_p$, $p>1$ according to a [Theorem of Browder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorems_in_infinite-dimensional_spaces). It would be almost incredible to have for $\ell_{\infty}$ a fixed-point free map that is affine $x\mapsto A x + b$, mapping the ball to itself.  I think now that fix-point theory is very interesting!

Comment: It seems that there are no examples with Lipschitz constant $1$. In a survey paper of W.A. Kirk: Fixed point theory of nonexpansive mappings, LNM 886, p. 489 I found the following result: Closed balls in $L^\infty(\Omega,\mu)$ over a finite or $\sigma$-finite measure space have the fixed point property for nonexpansive self-mappings.

Comment: @Gerd:  Thank you, what a find! That is so interesting...

Comment: @Gerd: I found something related: there exist Lipschitz maps of the unit ball with a positive displacement ( $\inf \|x - f x\| > 0$ ) for any infinite dimensional normed space.  That is really amazing!  Search term : " Spheres in infinite-dimensional  normed spaces are Lipschitz contractible"

Comment: That's a really nice result. Thank you for the link.

Comment: This is indeed a very deep and beautiful result. It shows that Brouwer's fixed point theorem fails in infinite dimensional spaces in a very strong sense. It is also known that in any infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ there is lipschitz retraction from ball onto sphere. Now we can ask what is the smallest lipschitz constant of such retraction in a given Banach space. I believe the exact value of this constant is not known for any space.

Comment: @triple backflip: Yes indeed!  So  there exist a $k$-Lipschitz map from the ball to itself such that $\inf\|x - f(x)\|= \rho > 0$. Results of Goebel (quoted in the paper with the sphere) show that $\rho$ cannot be larger than a function of $k$, independent of the normed space.  It would be nice to find for $\ell_{\infty}$ some explicit example.  Beautiful stuff indeed!

Answer (score -1):

I think the following example should work.

Let $f:B_{l_{\infty}}\rightarrow B_{l_{\infty}}$ such that $f(x_1, x_2, ...) = (y_1, y_2, ...)$, with
$$
y_1 =
\begin{cases}
1\;\;\;\;\;\text{if $\|(x_1,x_2,...)\|_{\infty} < 1$} \\
0\;\;\;\;\;\text{if $\|(x_1,x_2,...)\|_{\infty} = 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
and $y_n = x_{n-1}$ for $n>1$. It is obvious that is well defined.

Now I prove this function is continuous. Let $x=(x_1, x_2, ...)$, $x'=(x'_1, x'_2, ...)$ be elements of $B_{l_{\infty}}$ and let $f(x)=(y_1, y_2, ...)$ and $f(x')=(y'_1, y'_2, ...)$. Fix $0<\varepsilon<1$ and suppose $\|f(x)-f(x')\|_{\infty} < \varepsilon$.
Since $\varepsilon < 1$, we have then by definition that $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$ iff $\|x'\|_{\infty}=1$ (otherwise, we would have $\|f(x)-f(x')\|_{\infty}=1$). But then, we have $|x_n-x'_n|<\varepsilon$ for each $n$ (by definition of $f$) and so $\|x-x'\|_{\infty}\leq \varepsilon$. So $f$ is continuous.

Finally, suppose by contradiction that $x$ is a point fixed by $f$. By induction and the definition of $f$ it follows that $x_n=x_1$ for each $n$. Now, if $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$ we have $x = f(x)=(0, 0, 0, ...)$ and this is not possible; so $\|x\|_{\infty}<1$, but then $x=f(x)=(1, 1, 1, ...)$ and this is not possible too. So we get a contradiction.

Comment: You proved continuity of $f^{-1}$, not continuity of $f$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Right, thank you.

Comment: Actually it is Lipschitz, anyway, as orangeskid found.